# VSCode problem matcher with backtick in filename

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

My project has files like "Bar`1.cs" to represent generic types, as is done in the dotnet SDK.

My build task contains `"problemMatcher": { "base": "$msCompile" }`.

When such a file has errors/warnings, I get this:

> /home/username/project/Foo/Bar`1.Tests.cs (458,23): warning 123: some warning [/home/username/project/Foo.Tests.csproj]

...which is fine. But I cannot control-click on that filename to open it. The file's path is not underlined as normal - there is a clickable part before the bactick, and after.

How can I fix the click behaviour without changing filenames (impossible)?

Comment: File an issue??

Comment: @stuartd Thanks Stuart. So you believe it's a bug then, rather than my config?

Comment: probably backticks are not part of the regex that matches the filepath, or backticks are not in the `\w` regex set

Comment: Filed an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156288).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to be been [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156288).